# How to debug a POST 500 error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes, mandrill

I'm trying to set up inbound emails in Rails 3.2 app using Mandrill and Griddler.

I have installed the Griddler gem, and set up the necessary GET and POST routes. If I now navigate to myapp.com/email_processor in the browser I see an OK response as expected. If I run rake routes, the final entry is

```
email_processor POST     /email_processor(.:format)        griddler/emails#create
```

However, in Mandrill I have set up the mailbox routes but when I "send test" I get

`Webhook failed with error: POST to http://myapp.com/email_processor failed with 500: We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)`

I have successfully got this working on another app, so it is definitely possible, and I must be overlooking something in this app's set up. But I've hit a brick wall with where to look.

How can I systematically test and debug this external post error, to figure out why it is failing?

Comment: You don't have any logs in log/development.log ?